# CodeIgniter - Load scripts in footer view from content view file

Tags: codeigniter, buffer, delay

I have a view module that has the html and the javascript for uploading files.  I want the scripts to be loaded in the footer (just as an example).  So basically the view file should be able to alter the contents of the footer or header.  I am attempting to do this by reading the page first into buffer and then outputting the contents into the template file.

My controller has a function that looks like this -

```
public function test()
{
    ob_start();
    $this->load->view('content');  // uploader module
    ob_end_clean();
    $this->load->view('template', array($out1, $out2));  // ideally this will be output into a template file.  right now i'm just trying to echo it
}
```

My uploader module looks like this -

```
<div>some div for uploading</div>
<?php $out1 = ob_get_contents(); ?>
<?php ob_clean(); ?>

<script>
Logic for uploading that needs to go in the footer
</script>
<?php $out2 = ob_get_contents(); ?>
<?php ob_clean(); ?>
```

The template file would look like this -

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo $out1; ?>

<scripts>other javascript code and includes</script>
<?php echo $out2; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

However I am unable to save the buffer contents and pass it back into the controller ($out1, $out2).  Does anyone know how I can implement this?  The goal is basically to delay-load javascript code but have the javascript code reside in the content files to make it easier to code.  What's the best way to do this?  Do I need a global array or a new parent controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass variables between views like so:

```
<? ob_start(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var foo = 66;
  console.log(foo + 16);
</script>
<? $this->load->var('my_script', ob_get_clean()) ?>
```

If you run the above code in a view (or a controller, for that matter) ^^, the buffer's contents will be available in any views which are loaded later as `$my_script`.